# solr - save last_index_time in UTC

Tags: solr, solr4

When I compare documents from the db using

in my data-config.xml I am using deltaQuery attribute in order to compare

```
deltaQuery="select...
            from...
            where...
            myDocTable.LastModificationTime > '${dih.last_index_time}"
```

problem is that my dbtable value is datetime offset and not datetime.
Can I save the LastModificationTime with the "+X.00 GMT" time ?
Thanks.